# Having a string with a path to a folder, how do I convert it into File to be able to open it using getDesktop.open()?

Tags: java

I have a configuration file:

```
PropertiesConfiguration conf = new PropertiesConfiguration("config/conf.file")
```

which contains a string with a path to file:

```
folder = /path/to/folder
```

I get this value and assign it to a variable:

```
String folderToOpen = conf.getString("folder");
```

Is there any way to be able to open the folder using this:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(folderToOpen);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(newFile(folderToOpen));
```